# joomla - router change url when getting the name of product

Tags: joomla

I have build my own component in joomla and client wants now a friendly urls f.e
website.com/someplace/{product-id}-{product-name}. So i Build my own router like this.

```
function componentBuildRoute(&$query)
{
$segments = [];

if (isset($query['view'])) {
    $segments[] = "szkolenie";
    unset($query['view']);
}

if (isset($query['product_id'])) {
    $productName = JFilterOutput::stringURLSafe(strtolower(getProductName($query['product_id'])));
    $newName = $query['product_id'] . '-' . $productName;
    $segments[] = $newName;

    unset($query['product_id']);
}
return $segments;
}
```

and parse route function

```
function componentParseRoute($segments)
{
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
$item =& $menu->getActive();
$count = count($segments);

switch ($item->query['view']) {
    case 'catalogue' : {
        $view = 'training';
        $id = $segments[1];
    }
        break;
}

$data = [
    'view' => $view,
    'product_id' => $id
];
return $data;
}
```

While on the end of buildroute function segments are ok I have exactly what I want that on the beginning of parse route I have something like 
website.com/szkolenie/1-krakow <-- I dont know wtf is this krakow( I know it is city i Poland) but still where is it get from ? The getProductName function implementation is

```
function getProductName($productId)
{
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('#__component_training.id as id, #__component_product' . name)
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__component_training'))
    ->where('#__s4edu_product.product_id = ' . $productId)
    ->leftJoin('#__component_product ON 
#__component_training.product_id=#__component_product.product_id');
$training = $db->loadObject();
return trim($training->name);
}
```

So taking all this into consideration I think that something is happening between the buildRoute and parseRoute, something what filters the $segment[1] variable, but how to disable that and why is it happening ?

P.S
Please do not send me to https://docs.joomla.org/Joomla_Routes_%26_SEF
I already know all the tutorials on joomla website which contains anything with sef.

P.S.S

It is built on joomla 3.7.0

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a product named "krakow" ?

If not you can try to remove the $productName from the build function, just to check if this "krakow" is added automaticaly or it's from the getProductName() function.

Also i noticed that you have an error i guess in the function getProductName()

```
->where('#__s4edu_product.product_id = ' . $productId)
```

It's should be

```
->where('#__component_product.product_id = ' . $productId)
```